# mapStyle Night mode doesn't change the map style for a while?

Tags: android, google-maps

Selecting Night mode doesn’t change the screen for a while, and then the edge outside of the “night mode” goes to day as you move:

I am using

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
```

I just set map style in my **Fragment**

```
 boolean success = googleMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(getActivity(), R.raw.style_json));

 if (!success) {
       Log.e("TripFragment", "Style parsing failed.");
 }
```

Referred [Map Styling](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/styling)

What's problem here? How to solve this ?

[image]

Comment: It seems that the map tiles are not loading (lack of Internet connection?) and you are vieweing the white map background which doesn't style

Comment: @antonio Exactly. Some times is happened.